# How do I avoid "music" customization in music sub folders?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, music

Any time I open sub folders of the Music folder on this system containing MP3s with Explorer, they **always** have the `music` customization, but I tend to use file-naming conventions that don't make this customization necessary... I'd rather just see a `general` view.

I'm using Windows 7 Home Premium, Compaq CQ2014 (2011).

How do I avoid "music" customization in music sub folders?

Answer (score 1):

## Change Music folder "library optimization"

- Open Windows Explorer and navigate to **Libraries**, it should be in your left navigation menu as one of the shortcuts (if not, try here: `C:\Users\user\My Music`)
- Right click on the Music folder and click on **Properties**
- See the middle setting which says `Optimize this library for:` - this is likely set to **Music**. Change it to **General Items**

Now you will get the regular general view :)